# High voltage coaxial probe measurements

Tags: power-electronics, voltage-measurement, high-speed, coax

I am designing a high voltage motor controller and I want to validate the switching circuitry to ensure there's no excessive ringing behavior.

I had an idea to use something like an SMA or u.FL connector with an adapter to a BNC cable that I could plug into my scope, but couldn't figure out how to safely attenuate the signal. The voltage I'm measuring can exceed 500V and if I used a simple resistor divider, I'm concerned with the source impedance being too high and causing reflections in the measurement cable which would completely invalidate any overshoot/pre-shoot measurements. The best solution I had was to use an attenuator composed of 1M resistors and a high-speed unity buffer to generate the output signal at a known impedance but this is expensive in terms of board area.

[This white paper from TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt627/slyt627.pdf) seems to suggest what I was talking about above but I was hoping there was something simpler that wasn't created to sell a product.

EDIT: Could I perhaps design this system with high impedance circuitry only and operate the scope in high impedance mode? I am concerned about retaining a high enough bandwidth with such a design

Comment: IMHO, this can be difficult.  You need to make a capacitively compensated resistive divider. If you want high bandwidths, keep the impedances low.  Use a 50 ohm shunt resistor. You must control the physical construction of your attenuator so the parasitic capacitances are well controlled and repeatable.  The bridging capacitance across the input resistor will form a voltage divider with the capacitance of the scope cable. Getting high bandwidth is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to trust what the scope shows you, then rent a TEK HV probe. And keep the GND lead very short.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question, this might actually sound like my only reasonable options given that I have many signals to probe and an active buffer on each would get expensive quickly

Answer (score 0):

> The voltage I'm measuring can exceed 500V and if I used a simple
>   resistor divider, I'm concerned with the source impedance being too
>   high and causing reflections in the measurement cable which would
>   completely invalidate any overshoot/pre-shoot measurements.

I think you can safely use a resistor divider. If you attenuated at 500:1 you’d get a signal amplitude of 1 volt out for 500 volts in and any scope would be ok with this.

You can tailor the resistors to give a 50 ohm output quite easily if the lower one is chosen to be 50 ohms because the upper resistance in the potential divider would be 499 times higher and of course, can be made by series combinations of resistors. So the effective net resistance presented to the cable feed would be about 0.2% shy of 50 ohms (49.9 ohms) and won’t be an issue.

But, choose resistors that have an adequate voltage rating: some SMD types may only be rated at 50 volts but 1206 types can be 500 volt rated so don’t skimp in this area.

However, given the likely frequencies involved, not terminating correctly probably won’t cause issues for tens of metres of coax feed.

Comment: I actually need rather high frequencies because I'm trying to measure the switching the edges which are about 6ns.
If I used a 50 ohm resistor on the low side, I'd be dissipating around 10W in the high side resistor which would not be possible to dissipate in a package with low enough inductance if I understand things right

Comment: At 50% duty it’ll be 5 watts but I take your point. Maybe use a capacitive divider and End terminate the cable in an appropriate impedance. You can use combinations of parallel resistors and capacitors too but maybe go for 5000:1 attenuation. Also, if you have a decent equivalent model of the resistors, use a simulation tool to look at possibilities. A sim tool will easily predict any anomalies.